# Broadcast Receiver service feedback with activity not work

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver

i created a Broadcast Receiver for service feedback with activity. But this not work. Debugger -- after calling sendBroadcast from the service, skips this (LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);) line and does not cause Activity

```
This is Activity
package com.example.my;

 BroadcastReceiver br;
public static final String RECEIVE_JSON = 
"com.example.my.RECEIVE_JSON";
 public class cama extends AppCompatActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    xcxc();
    xcx();
            }

    public void xcxc()
    {
     br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_JSON)) {
        String serviceJsonString = intent.getStringExtra("json");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Test!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
        }
         }
        };
   }
public void xcx()
{
    LocalBroadcastManager bManager;
    bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_JSON);
    bManager.registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
}

      @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (br != null) {
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    }
       }
```

This is Service

```
package com.example.my;
public class MyService extends Service
      @Override
     public void onCreate() {
       do_anything();
         }
     public void do_anything()
     {Intent RTReturn = new Intent(cama.RECEIVE_JSON);
     RTReturn.putExtra("json", "ole");
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);}
```

Comment: provide complete broadcast code of activity

Comment: This full cod with BroadcastReceiver in Activity

Comment: how you are creating `xcxc()` in `onCreate()` ??

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cama);
    xcxc();

Comment: show your manifest file...

Comment: and also where you are starting service. Is your service staring successfully ??

Comment: I use LocalBroadcastManager, so I did not write anything in the manifest. In the service it starts, the debugger sees it      if (camera == null)
     {
         Intent RTReturn = new Intent(cama.RECEIVE_JSON);
         RTReturn.putExtra("json", "ole");
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(RTReturn);} camera.unlock();

Comment: Dear are you staring the service.??? I have tried your code with global braodcast send system.. It is working fine !!

Comment: And one more thing, you are registering broadcast to `LocalBroadcastManager` and unregistering to Activity

Comment: Yes, i start service with camera and debugger stops at "sendBroadcast(RTReturn);" Then force step into with debugger-after 2 step initialization debugger exit without nulls and errors.    I did everything as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager , but nothing changed.

Comment: How do you "start service with camera". What does that mean?

Comment: @АнатолийСолнцевский Have you tries my solution ?

Comment: @Mohit Yes, this not work for me.

Comment: what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

just use inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

```
LocalBroadcastManage 
mlocal = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

mlocal.sendBroadcast(YOUR Reciever)
```